# Cannot get Find Method's named arguments to work even with old code that use to work

Tags: vba, excel, methods, find, arguments

Out of nowhere I started to have the weirdest problem. When trying to use the find method the named argument LookAt stopped working. It seems like the compiler doesn't even recognize it anymore. I went back to some old macros that also used this and the LookAt stopped working there too! I thought it might be my Excel or computer so I tried 3 different computers and they all are having the same issue. Am I going crazy?? Here is an example of the code:

```
ElseIf AcctRef = "INTERPLANT FX AD" Then
        TransRow = Sheets(Plant).Range("F12:F50").Find("FX REVALUATION", lookat:=xlPart).Row
        Range("G" & TransRow).Value = Amount
```

You also might notice that the LookAt:= doesn't auto capitalize like it should. For now the workaround I'm using is this:

```
ElseIf AcctRef = "INTERPLANT FX AD" Then
        TransRow = Sheets(Plant).Range("F12:F50").Find("FX REVALUATION", , , xlPart).Row
        Range("G" & TransRow).Value = Amount
```

But this is pretty obnoxious. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: It doesn't always capitalise, that is not necessarily a problem. Are you saying it doesn't function properly?

Comment: Type `Dim LookAt` somewhere, hit enter, delete that declaration. Fixed.